# Kapacitor is taking a wrong time format

Tags: time-series, influxdb, kapacitor

I'm using InfluxData stack for anomaly detection in time series data, using InfluxDB and Kapacitor.

I collected some open source [samples](https://github.com/numenta/NAB/blob/master/data/realKnownCause/nyc_taxi.csv) and set the following tick script for detecting anomalies:

```
batch
    .query('select mean(value) from "nycTaxi"."default"."nycTaxi"')
        .period(1h)
        .every(2h)
        .groupBy(time(1h))
.mapReduce(influxql.percentile('mean', 90.0))
    .eval(lambda: sigma("percentile"))
        .as('sigma')
        .keep('percentile', 'sigma')
    .alert()
        .warn(lambda: "sigma" > 2.0)
        .log('/path/alerts.log')
        .crit(lambda: "sigma" > 3.0)
        .log('/path/alerts.log')
```

Obtaining alerts like the following:

```
 {"id":"nycTaxi:nil",
  "message":"nycTaxi:nil is WARNING",
  "time":"2016-09-13T14:43:21.892057062Z",
  "level":"WARNING",
  "data":{  
    "series":[  
      {  
        "name":"nycTaxi",
        "columns":[  
          "time",
          "percentile",
          "sigma"
        ],
        "values":[  
          [  
            "2016-09-13T14:43:21.892057062Z",
            1279,
            2.002345963142575
  ]]}]}}
```

To record the data I used this line `kapacitor record batch -start 2014-07-01T00:00:00Z -stop 2015-02-31T00:00:00Z -name nyc`

For some reason Kapacitor interprets the time as a 2016 date when in the DB the oldest date is 2015-01-31. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted an [issue in the Kapacitor repo](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/234) and the solution to my problem was to use the following line for replaying the data `kapacitor replay -id RECORDING_ID -name nyc -fast -rec-time`. The key here is the flag `-rec-time` which solved the issue.

Kudos to [Nathanielc](https://github.com/nathanielc) that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

InfluxDb feeds Kapacitor with data kind of *in real-time* (it's not really intended to go backwards through all your historical data, it was meant as in-time analysis/alerting tool).

Your current query basically just looks at the most recent data (1h) so that's why you're seeing 2016 in there. That is by design. If you want to check for anomalies in your historical data, you will have to write a small program (for example using an InfluxDb library for the language of your choice) which will go through all your old data hour-by-hour, fetch it and from there analyze it. You could also perhaps use [backfills](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/query_language/continuous_queries/#backfilling) for this.

Comment: But see that the date says `2016-09-13`, and we are not on that date (and it's impossible to be in that date because is the future).

Comment: @MartinAparicioPons - True, that part might be a bug. You might want to ask on influxdata github page. What is the newest date that you have in influx? Which versions of influxdb and kapacitor are you using? I know they changed the timestamp format I believe when influxdb v0.9.6 came out. Up until then, timestamps were unix-style timestamps, after that they became nice, human readable ISO-standard timestamps. So perhaps there is a missmatch there.

Comment: You are right, I'm submitting an issue in the repo. I'm using the latest version of Influx and Kapacitor (0.10), available from the influxData webpage.